# VB.NET Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 - Select by col

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb, ms-jet-ace

How to make Sql Select by column number and not by name with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 - Excel?

Ex: Select [Col1], [Col4], [Col5] from [dados$]

Comment: F1, F4, F5 - Header=NO in connstring

Comment: @Steve - Could not find installable ISAM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797978/how-to-resolve-could-not-find-installable-isam-error-for-ole-db-provider-mic

Comment: Yea working... Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'... Ty @Steve